# Ubuntu server refusing to boot - digital ocean

Tags: ubuntu

When ever I power on my server it comes up with this in the console, and refuses to boot, I am in desperate need of getting this going as it has all my websites on it 12+ And my keystores for my apps.

[image]

Comment: Does Digital Ocean let you boot into a recovery mode or something? Or mount the disk image into another instance?  What about your backups?

Comment: If you do manage to boot recovery mode or something, I'm pretty sure [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776003/fixing-a-systemd-service-203-exec-failure-no-such-file-or-directory) is your solution.

Comment: I can boot into recovery fine. I just don't know how to use it, apose to the unix system terminal. As in recovery it's just bash